# How to call the object of a control created on click event of a button into the click vent of another button?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I has added a panel on the click event of a button at runtime i.e. every time we will click on the button the panel will be called.

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Location = new Point(10, (childrenCount - 1) * 280);
p.Width = 800;
p.Height = 250;
/****some code****/
this.Controls.Add(p);
```

Now i have dropped a new button on my form and i want that on the click event of the form the panel get removed. So how can i call object p of this panel class on the click event of this button.

**And how to add background to a panel at runtime**
Here is the panel in which i want to add background

```
public void addchildbtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { //Adds a child
           try
           {
               rmvchildclicklbl.Enabled = true;
               remvchildbtn.Enabled = true;
               no_childnumlbl.Text = (childrenCount).ToString();
               childclmns clmn = new childclmns();
               clmn.Location = new Point(100, 200);
               clmn.Name = "column" ;
               this.Controls.Add(clmn);
               childrenCount++;
               Panel p = new Panel();
               p.Location = new Point(10, (childrenCount - 1) * 280);
               p.Width = 800;
               p.Height = 250;
               p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
               p.ForeColor = Color.Black;
               p.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
               p.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"image\baby.bmp");
               p.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
               // p.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
               Label lblchild = new Label();
               lblchild.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
               lblchild.Location = new Point(20, 50);
               lblchild.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
               lblchild.Text = "Child  " + (childrenCount - 1);
               TextBox tName = new TextBox(); //TextBox for the name
               tName.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
               tName.Location = new Point(120, 50);
               tName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 60);
               tName.Text = "";
               MonthCalendar calendar = new MonthCalendar(); //Calendar to choose the birth date
               calendar.Location = new Point(310, 40);
               ComboBox bloodGroup = new ComboBox(); //ComboBox for the blood group
               bloodGroup.Location = new Point(650, 50);
               bloodGroup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 60);
               for (Enum.Blood_Group l = Enum.Blood_Group.O_negative; l <= Enum.Blood_Group.AB_positive; l++)
               {
                   bloodGroup.Items.Add(l);
               }
               p.Controls.Add(lblchild);
               p.Controls.Add(tName);
               p.Controls.Add(calendar);
               p.Controls.Add(bloodGroup);
               this.Controls.Add(p);
               p.Name = "panel" + childrenCount;
               panels.Add(p);
               //Summit button location
               button1.Visible = true;
               int j=350, k= 300;
               k = k + ((childrenCount - 1) * 280);
               button1.Location = new Point(j, k);
               btnht= k.ToString();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }

       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the panel you want to delete.

There are many ways to do it.

You could search through the `Controls` collection backwards and remove the last added Panel, or for example, store the added panels in a list somewhere so you can remove it:

```
// in the form class
List<Panel> panels = new List<Panel>();

// in your add button click event
/****some code****/
panels.Add(p);
this.Controls.Add(p);

// in your remove button click event
if (panels.Any())
{
    var panel = panels.Last();
    this.Controls.Remove(panel)
    panels.Remove(panel);
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
// in your add button click event
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Location = new Point(10, (childrenCount - 1) * 280);
p.Width = 800;
p.Height = 250;
p.Name = "panel" + childrenCount;
/****some code****/
this.Controls.Add(p);


// in your remove button click event
this.Controls.RemoveByKey("panel" + childrenCount);
childrenCount--;
```

Comment: dear if i want to add a background image to this panel than how how can i add it 'p.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("panel1.BackgroundImage")));' but it is saying The name resources does not exist in the current context

Comment: where do you have this image?

Comment: in the folder 'image' in my project

Comment: `p.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"image\fileName.bmp");` or, if you already have it on another panel, you can use `p.BackgroundImage = otherPanel.BackgroundImage`

Comment: but dear this code is giving errors

Comment: "Parameter is not valid "and it is an exception

Comment: Can you show me your exact code?

Comment: yes of-course. i have edited it in my questions

Comment: background image code i used is mentioned in that

Comment: Probably the file doesn't exist there. Note that the path you use is relative to the executable (in the bin\release or bin\debug folder). Try using the full path (or correct the relative path) and it should work

Comment: means i have to give the path of the image folder where it lies in my computer (hard-disk folder path)